# PHP survey make user vote once only by IP address

Tags: php, ip-address

i have created an online survey in PHP and it works fine with one exception.

I would like my voters to be restricted to one vote only and i've decided to track them by their IP addresses. Unfortunately the code i have come up with does not seem to be working at all:

```
<?php

session_start();
require('execute.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

$track = ($_POST['track']);
$address = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if(empty($_POST['track']))
{
    echo 'Please select one of the tracks';
}
else
{
    $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim ($track));
}

if(empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
echo '';
}
else
{
$i = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim ($address));
}


if(!empty($_POST['track']))
{
$q = "SELECT track_id FROM track WHERE address = '$i'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
if(mysqli_num_rows($r) != 0)
{
    echo 'You have already voted';
}
else
{
$q = "INSERT INTO track (track, ip_address) VALUES ('$t', '$i')"; 
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
echo 'Thank you for voting';
mysqli_close($dbc);
}
}

}
?>
```

The line where I'm having the problem is

```
$q = "SELECT track_id FROM track WHERE address = '$i'";
```

The IP records are saved in the database but the condition fails to execute properly and so the user still gets to vote multiple times.

Any suggestions welcome.

Regards

Jacek

Comment: what is variable `$i` here?

Comment: using ip is pointless, ip !=person. 1 ip could be many people, and multiple ip's one person.

Comment: I see one problem - you have this line "$q = "SELECT track_id FROM track WHERE address = '$i'";", but you also have this line "$q = "INSERT INTO track (track, ip_address) VALUES ('$t', '$i')"; "

WHERE address looks like it should be WHERE ip_address from the second query.